# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL', ImageTk

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library, mu

I am on Windows 10 and my python 3 code is as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

root = Tk()
root.title("Images")
root.iconbitmap("C:/Users/[name]/mu_code/GUI Practice/icon.ico")

# my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("threat.jpg")


button_quit = Button(root, text="Exit Program", command=root.destroy)
button_quit.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I try to run this it gives the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "c:\users[name]\mu_code\gui practice\images.py", line 2, in 
> from PIL import ImageTk, Image
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PIL'

I have used pip install to download Pillow and attempted to download it to different locations to fix the problem but could not as the command prompt stated that the module was already downloaded. How can I fix this issue?

Edit:

```
import Image
```

or

```
import ImageTk
```

doesn't work either.

I have already run pip install Pillow and have one interpreter, being 'Mu'

Comment: Have you run ```pip install pillow```

Comment: I have. I downloaded the module and any additional tries has stated that it is already downloaded

Comment: Do you have 2 interpreters?

Comment: Nope. I only have 'Mu' installed.

Comment: Are you using anaconda as a package manager? Conda and pip packages co-existing together may cause problems. Also, the python native pil and pillow can not co exist together. Can you please uninstall and re-install pillow?

Comment: I am not using conda. I didn't download native pil in the first place. I still tried to uninstall and reinstall Pillow but no luck.

Comment: If you are using *Mu* editor, see [Installing Python Packages](https://codewith.mu/en/tutorials/1.1/pypi),

Comment: Thank you very much! This was the issue.

Answer (score 1):

What you see here as `PIL` is actually `pillow` library

```
from PIL import ImageTk, Image
```

Run the command:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Check out for [`PIL`](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/)

Comment: This is the command I have run. In fact, trying to pip install PIL doesn't even work. I tried out of desperation.

Comment: I use anaconda so I installed it through there and it works :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

What I did is:

1. Open CMD typed "pip install pillow" if you have not yet install pillow
2. Copied "PIL" folder from
   [C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages]
3. Then paste it to
   [C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib]

Answer (score -1):

Try to use `import Image`, and PIL starts working ( it works in my case):

```
import Image
```

instead of

```
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Image'